# Разбить строку на массив с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php

Есть строка, в которой есть такой текст:

`....... <strong>1.</strong> ...... ........ <strong>2.</strong>`

Мне нужно разбить строку на массив, чтобы разделитель был `<strong>*Любое число*[точка]</strong>`

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Сам не силен в регулярных выражениях, знаю что есть функция `preg_split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

что-то вроде такого

```
$result = preg_split('/<(strong)>\d+\.<\/\1>/', $txt);
```